# script that checks if another script has an error, then kills and restarts screen and script

Tags: python, matlab, shell, crash, try-catch

I have a matlab scipt on a cluster that pings an API, but after a couple hours (2-4h), the script will have an unexpected error which we believe comes from pinging the API too many times.

I want to create a script (not sure if it should be a .sh or .py) that essentially monitors the matlab script and once it reads that it crashed, it will kill the screen, make a new screen, and run the matlab script again.

I'm currently doing this restart manually, but it is very inefficent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Did you have a question?  I don't see a question, and questions are what this site is all about.  "I want..." is not a question.

Comment: I'd like to help you, but there are too many unknowns here for me to know what to recommend.  How will your new script monitor the Matlab script to know that it has crashed?  What is involved in running a new screen and getting Matlab going again?  Do you have to do specific things to set up the environment in which the Matlab script runs?  The best thing you can do is show us as much progress as you can.  If you can't start to write the script, you could at least give a detailed description of what you do to run the current script manually.

Comment: MATLAB has a build-in try-catch routine. I'd start from there. Otherwise just monitor for the process id with _ps_ or similar system tools, restart as needed. Or, you can implement a heart-beat function in the script, and restart when heart-beat updates timed out etc.